# Collision between ball and curve as graphics objects

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I am trying to make a game where I bounce a ball off of the ground which is drawn as a closed curve (The green part), I just don't know how I would go about calculating the collision between the ball and curve.

[image: picture of the graphics]

I've drawn both the ball and curve using graphics in a picturebox, I imagine I have to do it mathematically as I can't find any builtin functionality in Visual basic that lets me do it.

My code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim BallSpeedY, BallSpeedX As Double
    Dim BallLoc As Point

    Dim Start As Boolean = False

    Dim gameTime As Decimal = 60.1
    Dim gameTimeFont As New Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold)



    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

        'Size of the picturebox that is being drawn on
        PictureBox1.Width = Me.Width
        PictureBox1.Height = Me.Height - 24

        DrawGame(False, False, True)

    End Sub

    Private Sub DrawGame(refreshMap As Boolean, drawBall As Boolean, drawTime As Boolean)

        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)

        Static startcornerpt As PointF
        Static firstpt As PointF
        Static pt2 As PointF
        Static pt3 As PointF
        Static pt4 As PointF
        Static pt5 As PointF
        Static lastpt As PointF
        Static Endcornerpt As PointF



        ' Clears the window
        g.Clear(Color.White)

        If refreshMap Then
            Randomize() ' The rnd seed would always be the same if this is not done

            ' Creates 5 points chosen at random positions on the window within certain parameters
            startcornerpt = New PointF(0, Me.Height)
            pt2 = New PointF(Me.Width * 0.2, Me.Height * ((39 * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
            firstpt = New PointF(0, pt2.Y * 0.5 * 2)
            pt3 = New PointF(Me.Width * 0.4, Me.Height * ((39 * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
            pt4 = New PointF(Me.Width * 0.6, Me.Height * ((39 * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
            pt5 = New PointF(Me.Width * 0.8, Me.Height * ((39 * Rnd() + 30) / 100))
            lastpt = New PointF(Me.Width, pt5.Y * 0.5 * 2)
            Endcornerpt = New PointF(Me.Width, Me.Height)
        End If

        ' Draws the map with the 5 points
        Dim curvepoints As PointF() = {startcornerpt, firstpt, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, lastpt, Endcornerpt}
        g.FillClosedCurve(Brushes.PaleGreen, curvepoints)




        If drawBall Then
            ' Draws the ball
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, BallLoc.X, BallLoc.Y, 20, 20)
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, BallLoc.X, BallLoc.Y, 20, 20)

            ' Accelerates speed
            BallSpeedY = BallSpeedY - 1

            ' Update position
            BallLoc = New Point(BallLoc.X + BallSpeedX, BallLoc.Y - BallSpeedY)



        End If

        If drawTime Then

            gameTime = gameTime - 0.1
            gameTime.ToString()

            g.DrawString(gameTime, gameTimeFont, Brushes.Black, Me.Width / 2 - 120, Me.Height * 0.025) ' Draws the gametime on screen, 
            ' Width is set to be around the middle of the screen while height is just under the strip menu.

        End If

        PictureBox1.Refresh()

    End Sub

    Private Sub StartToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartToolStripMenuItem.Click

        If Start = False Then

            gameTime = 60.1

            'Resets ball for testing
            BallLoc.X = 800
            BallLoc.Y = 300
            BallSpeedY = 0

            'Starts the timers
            Gravity.Start()
            Movement.Start()

            Start = True

        ElseIf Start = True Then

            ' Resets the ball
            Dim ballloc As New Point(800, 300)


            Gravity.Stop()
            Movement.Stop()

            Start = False

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub NewMapToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewMapToolStripMenuItem.Click

        ' Creates a new map
        DrawGame(True, False, False)
        Start = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Movement_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Movement.Tick

        ' Starts movement of the ball
        DrawGame(False, True, True)

    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT: Collision now works with these additions:

```
Dim wider = CType(ground.Clone(), GraphicsPath)
    Using widenizer As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black, ballDiameter)
        wider.Widen(widenizer)
    End Using
```

And:

```
 If ground.IsVisible(BallLoc) OrElse wider.IsVisible(BallLoc) Then
            BallSpeedY = BallSpeedY + 50 ' rebound on collision

        End If
```

Comment: First things first, if you want to generate random numbers then don't use `Randomize` and `Rnd`. You're not using VB6. Create an instance of the `Random` class and use that.

Comment: As for the question, are you saying that you want to keep the blue ball in the white section and prevent it going into the green section? It's just that you say that the ground is drawn as a line but, in GDI+ terms, "line" implies straight line between two points. The answer is the same in principle but the implementation would be far more complex with a curve than a line.

Comment: If you're talking about a curve then I think that your best bet would be to create a `GraphicsPath` that represents the "ground" and then call its `IsVisible` method to see whether a `Point` representing the ball is within it. `GraphicsPath` has an `AddClosedCurve` method, so there's no issue adding that same curve as you're drawing. The decision to be made is what `Point` to use. Will you use all `Points` that are within the "ball" and loop? Just the centre? Just the lowest `Point`? Try to calculate the closest to the curve? That's up to you.

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney for the answer! You are correct in that I meant the closed curve and not a line. I will try what you suggested with GraphicsPath and come back to you.

Comment: One point worth mentioning is that, if you're going to create the `GraphicsPath` for collision detection anyway, it might be simplest to call `DrawPath` and/or `FillPath` to do the drawing as well.

Comment: What is the syntax for IsVisible supposed to look like? It seems to only accept a single point. Ideally I'd want it to use the point that is first to intersect aswell.

Comment: It does only accept a single `Point`. That's why I said that it's up to you to determine which `Point(s)` to use. If you want to actually find that intersection point then you'd have to represent both the curve and the ball mathematically.  It may be simpler to just choose four or eight points on the edge of the ball and call `IsVisible` for each of them. That's a fairly good approximation for most situations.

Comment: An easy way out here would be to `Clone()` the path and `Widen()` it using a `Pen` with the same width as your ball. Then simply check if the _center_ of the ball `IsVisible()` in either of the paths.

Comment: Still not entirely sure how to use `IsVisible`, I've tried making it tell me whether it triggers once it intersects with the closedcurve but it only triggers once the ball has exited the form. This is how I thought I was supposed to set it up `h.IsVisible(BallLoc.X, BallLoc.Y)` but that must be wrong in that case. Is it possible one of you can give me an example of IsVisible how it is supposed to work. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Humus see my "answer" - it couldn't fit in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below illustrates the comment I've added about using `Widen()` so you can test using the center of the ball.

It has been ages since I've done any VB.NET, but it does show the idea:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Partial Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim diameter As Integer = 10
        Dim path As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
        path.AddCurve(New Point() {New Point(0, 100), New Point(200, 200), New Point(400, 100)})
        path.AddLines(New Point() {New Point(400, 400), New Point(0, 400)})
        path.CloseAllFigures()
        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Green, path)
        Dim wider = CType(path.Clone(), GraphicsPath)
        Using widenizer As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black, diameter)
            wider.Widen(widenizer)
        End Using

        For x As Integer = 0 To 400 Step diameter
            For y As Integer = 0 To 400 Step diameter

                If path.IsVisible(x, y) OrElse wider.IsVisible(x, y) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, CType(x - diameter / 2, Single), CType(y - diameter / 2, Single), diameter, diameter)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, CType(x - diameter / 2, Single), CType(y - diameter / 2, Single), diameter, diameter)
                End If

            Next y
        Next x
    End Sub
End Class
```

It fills the area with circles, where the red ones are "touching" the ground:

[image]

Comment: You're using C# though, won't that have an effect or is it the same outcome either way? You're checking for if the ball is within the widened path here `for (int x = 0; x < 400; x += diameter)` correct? But what does it do? aren't you just widening the path even more?

Comment: Oh, sorry! Your question appeared in the `gdi+` filter and I failed to see the `vb.net` tag. It doesn't affect the outcome, though. The for-loops just represent the possible _positions_ for the ball - a collision check for one ball would consist of two `IsVisible` calls.

Comment: I get an insufficient memory error at wider.Widen(widenizer) now, commenting out that line fixes the problem but the application runs really slowly now.

Comment: I can't debug your code from here, I've tried adding complexity (1000 curves) to my example but no memory issues there.

Comment: It does slow down drastically then :P

Comment: Are there any parts of your code that can be cut off? currently I'm only using from `Dim wider = CType(path.clone(), graphicspath)` to `Next x` I know that's kind of stupid but do I actually need all of the other stuff? obviously I'm changing out path and other variables with my own.

Comment: The code just shows that you can have accurate results with two `GraphicsPath.IsVisible()` calls. You shouldn't include the x/y loops in your program. The code is a kind of proof of concept.

Comment: Thank you!!! it finally works! I only included the Cloning, aswell as the widening of the ground and the if statement with `IsVisible`, changed out the x, y with my coordinates for the ball and now it works. Thank you so much.